# Test for Poisson residuals in the analysis of variance model

Tags: r, anova, poisson

I try to find any way for test Poisson residuals like normals in `aov()`. In my hypothetical example:

```
# For normal distribution
x <- rep(seq(from=10, to=50, by=0.5),6)
y1 <- rnorm(length(x), mean=10, sd=1.5)

#Normality test in aov residuals
y1.av<-aov(y1 ~ x)
shapiro.test(y1.av$res)
#   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#
#data:  y1.av$res
#W = 0.99782, p-value = 0.7885
```

Sounds silly, OK!!

Now, I'll like to make a same approche but for Poisson distribution:

```
# For Poisson distribution
x <- rep(seq(from=10, to=50, by=0.5),6)
y2 <- rpois(x, lambda=10)

#Normality test in aov residuals
y2.av<-aov(y2 ~ x)
poisson.test(y2.av$res)
Error in poisson.test(y2.av$res) : 
  'x' must be finite, nonnegative, and integer
```

There is any stat approach for make this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are passing non-integers to `dpois`. This cannot be right. As for a poisson test, there's `poisson.test` in base package `stats`.

Comment: Thanks Rui, but doesn't work                                                                                                                                 # For Poisson distribution
 x <- rep(seq(from=10, to=50, by=0.5),6)
 y2 <- rpois(x, lambda=10)
 
 #Normality test in aov residuals                                                                      
y2.av<-aov(y2 ~ x)                                                                 
poisson.test(y2.av$res)
Error in poisson.test(y2.av$res) : 
  'x' must be finite, nonnegative, and integer

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior. The assumptions of anova include residuals normality with mean 0. You should expect negative residuals even if their distribution is (very) far from normal.

Comment: Rui than don't have any other analysis to test this kind of assumption for Poisson residuals?

Comment: Check out package DHARMa, including the intro where it talks about assumptions of GLM/GLMM's in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html).  You might find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could analyse your data below a counting context. Discrete data, such as variables of Poisson nature, can be analysed based on observed frequencies. You can formulate hypothesis testing for this task. Being your data `y` you can contrast the null hypothesis that `y` follows a Poisson distribution with some parameter lambda against the alternative hypothesis that `y` does not come from the Poisson distribution. Let's sketch the test with you data:

```
#Data
set.seed(123)
# For Poisson distribution
x <- rep(seq(from=10, to=50, by=0.5),6)
y2 <- rpois(x, lambda=10)
```

Now we obtain the counts, which are elemental for the test:

```
#Values
df <- as.data.frame(table(y2),stringsAsFactors = F)
df$y2 <- as.integer(df$y2)
```

After that we must separate the observed values `O` and its groups or categories `classes`. Both elements constitute the `y` variable:

```
#Observed values
O <- df$Freq
#Groups
classes <- df$y2
```

As we are testing a Poisson distribution, we must compute the lambda parameter. This can be obtained with Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE). The MLE for Poisson is the mean (considering we have counts and groups in order to determine this value), so we compute it with next code:

```
#MLE
meanval <- sum(O*classes)/sum(O)
```

Now, we have to get the probabilities of each class:

```
#Probs
prob <- dpois(classes,meanval)
```

Poisson distribution can go to infinite values, so we must compute the probability for the values that can be greater than our last group in order to have probabilities that sum to one:

```
prhs <- 1-sum(prob)
```

This probability can be easily added to the last value of our group in order to transform to account for values greater or equal to it (For example, instead of only having the probability that `y` equals to 20 we can have the probability that `y` is greater or equal to 20):

```
#Add probability
prob[length(prob)]<-prob[length(prob)]+prhs
```

With this we can conduct a goodness of fit test using `chisq.test()` function in `R`. It requires the observed values `O` and the probabilities `prob` that we have computed. Just a reminder that this test uses to set wrong degrees of freedom, so we can correct it by the formulation of the test that uses `k-q-1` degrees. Where `k` is the number of groups and `q` is the number of parameters computed (we have computed one parameter with MLE). Next the test:

```
chisq.test(O,p=prob)
```

The output:

```
Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  O
X-squared = 7.6692, df = 17, p-value = 0.9731
```

The key value from the test is the `X-squared` value which is the test statistic. We can reuse the value to obtain the real `p-value` (In our example, we have `k=18` and minus 2, the degrees of freedom are 16).

The `p.value` can be obtained with next code:

```
p.value <- 1-pchisq(7.6692, 16)
```

The output:

```
[1] 0.9581098
```

As this value is not greater that known significance levels we do not reject the null hypothesis and we can affirm that `y` comes from a Poisson distribution.